# Create a de-identified table

Tags: sql-server

I am being asked to create a de-identified table in SQL Server. The company gets weekly files that replaces their entire reporting database and they would like one of the tables de-identified. It is not connected to a network either. I was thinking of creating a member table that would stay on the server, have the de-identified number and member_id and join to one of the tables that is imported weekly by member_id. Does that sound like what should be done? Also, how would I account for new members that would not be on the member table? Would I need to do a unmatched query and find the ones who aren't on it and then create a de-identified number for them?

Comment: One note: if you are able to use your new object to re-identify the data, by HIPAA standards the table has not been de-identified.  Generally data is only considered de-identified for HIPAA if you can't go back and figure out what the original value was.  So you'd have to take all the unique MEMBER_ID values, give each of them a key, add that key to the table, and delete the original MEMBER_ID.  You couldn't persist it.  You should determine the exact business requirements for de-identification in your case.

Comment: @tbrookside thanks.  so you think I should create an entire new member table weekly? The set up at this place is the sql server isn't on a network so someone has to physically go to a room to run reports off the data. They want the de-identified on the network so one table can be reported on. Someone is going to have to put the table on a flash drive or external and then upload it to the reporting db.

Comment: Ah - that's slightly different.  It sounds like if you create an alternate key for the MEMBER_ID you can persist your crosswalk table, because you're keeping it off network.  It won't be possible for any user of the new table to join to the crosswalk table, so that should satisfy the standard.  Definitely get requirements clarification, though.

Comment: @tbrookside yeah it is a very weird setup. For ones that aren't on the new table as time goes on, do you think doing an unmatched and adding the missing ones is the best way to go?

Comment: What does "de-identified" even mean?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been around for a while, I'd suggest [de-identify sql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/de-identify-sql) to create de-identified tables:

- It runs from the command-line on SQL CREATE / INSERT statements
- It accepts a range of strategies for modifying data: simple redaction, replacement with fabricated values or more complicated coded approaches
- It will work on a single table or across an entire DB